# Python library/package code works outside library but trying to run inside library gives import error

Tags: python-3.x, import, error-handling

I have the following project structure:

```
src
    parser
        util.py
        tool.py

    CmdUtility.py
```

I want to be able to run util.py and tool.py as a standalone scripts, as well as CmdUtility.py as a standalone script. But I cannot due to import errors

in CmdUtility.py I have:

```
from parser import *
```

in util.py I have:

```
from parser.tool import *
```

in tool.py I have:

```
from parser.util import *
```

Compiling util.py and tool.py do not work, i get import error ImportError: No module named 'parser'. 
Compiling CmdUtility.py works fine and the program can run.

How do i make it so I can run any of these python scripts and not get an import error

Answer (score 0):

seems the path to 'parser' is not clear in the util.py or tool.py files. try appending the path:

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(Path('[specify current directory]').parent)
```

Comment: i added the imports into util.py and tool.py and still did not work, "ImportError: no module named 'tool'" in util.py , when CmdUtility.py is compiled- however tool.py and util.py compiled fine.